# Regex to match string containing two (or more) words in any order and case not sensitive

Tags: regex, string, go

Hope you guys can help me.

I need to make a string that alerts me when the following conditions are met:

1. Two (or more) words are identified in a message
2. It does not have to look just at the "whole" words but also at that ones that contain the text I am searching. For istance, I search for "error", it has to be alert me also when it founds "error**s**" or "errorless".
3. It should not to be case sensitive
4. It has to look at word1 and word2 but also viceversa, in others words it has to look at them irrespective of their order

I have played a while with regex101 but I have not been able to reach all conditions (condition # 4 is still missing).

You can find at the following link what I have been able to make:
https://regex101.com/r/Z4cE9A/5

Please note that I need matches with the following expressions characteristics:

Flavor: golang    /    Flag: single line

**Important note**: I cannot use the character "|" as it does not work properly on the system where I am going to use this string.

Any help would be more than appreciated. Thanks in advance for your support.

EDIT: I did confusion. The non functioning character is "|". However if possible is better to avoid also the "/" as I am not sure if it works. If you want we can provide me with two strings, one without the symbol "/" and one without, in case it does not work.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work: `(?i:.*Error.*http|.*http.*error)` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I did confusion. The non functioning character is "|". However, if possible, is better to avoid also the "/" as I am not sure if it works. So your proposed string unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Are you able to run more than one test?

Comment: I could do it but then it became time consuming when the number of words to search increase. I tought about this as backup solution but I would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: Then I think the real answer is to figure out how to use `|` in your REs. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It is a telegram not made by me and the developer told me that the strings with the symbol "|" do not work properly. Is there any workaround to the use of such symbol (as well as the symbol "/" if possible) expect the one to make multiple strings inverting the words?

Comment: Which telegram exactly? Apparently in Go you can use `%r` to switch to another delimiter, e.g. `%r|s/s|`. Generally backslash ``\`` escapes special characters, so possibly `\`(?:http.*error\|error.*http)\`` would work (raw string literal in backquotes), if you are passing in a string that is wrapped in a `|` delimited regex literal later.

Comment: I am sorry I did a typo. I wanted to say a telegram bot (I wrote not instead of bot). Bot's name is @junction_bot

Comment: @NetMage I did not hear from you since a while, are you thinking to an alternative string?

Comment: I don't think there is one. You need to figure out how to escape `|` to work.

Comment: @NetMage can you make a string without the symbol "/" where there is no need to repeat the words in all the orders that I want to look at? I am referring to this: (?i:.*Error.*http|.*http.*error) it became difficult to make a string like this when you have several words as you would have to write down all combinations of words.

Comment: Not with a Regular Expression.

Comment: @Netmage So I have a different question, can you make a string that works with golang flavor and single line regex flag? feel free to use whetever character and or symbol you think is necessary but please, make it in a way that if I have to search 4 words, I do not have to enter manually, into the string, one by one all combinations of the words I want to track (for istance word1 word2 word3 word4, then word2 word1 word3 word4, etc until I cover all combinations I am interested). This, together with flavor and regex flag are the only limitations. Hope you can make it work somehow in this way.

Comment: Answer is still not with a Regular Expression in Go - the RE engine isn't sufficient.

Comment: @NetMage so what flavor and regex flag you recommend for a working string? and what string? thank you

Comment: Using C#, this pattern `(?is)(?=.*http)(?=.*error)` only matches if both words exist in the string in any order with any case.

Comment: Of course, a lot of other languages (e.g. Perl) support lookahead as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
(?i:(http)|(error))
```

You can replace `http` and `error` with any other keywords that you are searching for.

To do that in Golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    keywords := []string{
        "error",
        "http",
    }
    p := "(?i:(" + strings.Join(keywords, ")|(") + "))"
    text := `
    Gran Turismo Sport

Shipment Error

Attempt
https://
`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(p)
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(text))
}
```

You can test that in Golang Playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/XOhNVBCh8Pt

EDIT:

Based on the new limitation of not being able to use the `|` char, I would suggest that you search using this:

`(?i:(error)?(http)?)`

This will always return true (or a list of empty strings in find all) but the good thing is you can filter out all the empty strings and you will end up with the result that you want.

This is a an example of this working in Golang Playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/miVC0hdLtQc

EDIT 2:
In case you want to make sure ALL the keywords are in the text change the `?` in regex with `{1,}`. Also you don't need the loop any more.

`(?i:(error){1,}(http){1,})`

This is an an example working in Golang Playground

https://play.golang.org/p/f9eFcvObDsA

Comment: I am sorry, I did confusion. The non functioning character is "|". However, if possible, is better to avoid also the "/" as I am not sure if it works. So your proposed string unfortunately does not work.

Comment: This doesn't work as it matches strings with only one word, either `http` or `error`. Trying taking out `https` from the test string.

Comment: @NetMage The question as I understood it was to find any word of a list of words in a string regardless of the order and regardless of prefix or suffix. This does exactly that. You can test it in the golang playground by commenting out either of the keywords and it will still return true.

Comment: @Radeon89 I edited my answer to make it work without `|`

Comment: The string have to search for ALL words and provide matches when all words are found, this irrespective of their order. Hope this clarify any doubt and my apologies if initially I have not been clear enough.

Comment: @Roshan Rush I tested the updated string (?i:(error)?(http)?) but I got matches also if just one of the two words is present. As I said in my last message above of few minutes ago, I would like to get matches only when all words of my interest are present. Thank you so much

Comment: @Radeon89 I guess I missunderstood your question and I thought you wanted to match any of the words regardless of the order. The solution is really simple, just change the `?` with `{1,}`. I'll post another edit to my answer

Comment: @Roshan Rush It seems that even this new string does not work, please check it here on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/2BHV4z/2/ it says no match. I copied and pasted the string so I am sure I did not make a typo. Let me know. Thank you

Comment: Using `{1,}` (which is just a long way of saying `+`) won't work because it fixes the order of the words.